# How to move webgl 2d scale origin from centre to top left?

Tags: canvas, 2d, webgl, move, scaling

I'm using a scale array as [sx, sy], which is initially set to [1,1].
I need to change the origin of scaling to the top left of the canvas. Is there any possible way with which I can do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You haven't provided enough details. Maybe [read some articles on WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) which cover [matrix math](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) which includes moving the origin as well as how to implement a canvas 2d like [matrix stack](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html)?

Comment: I asked, if there's any possible ways to perform scaling from top left corner of the canvas. I'm using an array [Sx,Sy] to scale for x and y values. This is scaling my object from center, which now I require it should be scaled from top left corner. Also, I do not want to use any matrix just for scaling in 2d.

Comment: Scaling is something that is unique to every individual's code. There is no "scaling" in WebGL. There is just math. Until you show us your code we have no idea how to answer. The articles I linked to point this out. They also give examples. The first article changes from working in clip space (the default) to working in pixels space with its own set of math with the origin in the bottom left. It then changes that to the top left. We can't help you if you don't show your code. Though if you read the articles you'll have your answer.